# why shrinkwrap not getting curve shape

Tags: modifiers

I have a oval shape with needful verts on it and a cylinder. I want to make the oval shape to wrap on it. Little bending shape with only shrinkwrap modifier.

[image]

[image]

When i add shrinkwrap modifier it looses its shape. Any help or suggestion how it works.

Comment: maybe because you've chosen the Nearest Vertex mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's because you have chosen *Nearest Vertex* mode in the modifier, so the vertices of your oval stick to the vertex of your cylinder mesh. Switch to *Nearest Surface Point* and it should work properly.